# Why are my items not showing up in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, awt

I'm fairly new to JFrame and I want to know why my items are not showing up on the window. I know i dont have a ActionHandler but I just want my textfield's to show up on my window. Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FirstGUI extends JFrame{
    public void GUI(){
       setTitle("Welcome");
       setResizable(false);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setVisible(true);
       setSize(600,600);

       JLabel title = new JLabel();
       title.setText("Apple Inc. Member Login Port");
       title.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));

       JTextField login = new JTextField("Login",10);

       JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField("Password");

       add(title);
       add(login);
       add(pass);

   }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        FirstGUI a = new FirstGUI();
        a.GUI();
    }
}
```

but when i run it i get this:

[image]

Comment: I believe you need to add your components to `context pane` and not directly to the frame. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html

Comment: @PM77-1 I believe since Java 5 this is not longer required as `JFrame#add` delegates to the content pane for your

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> but when i run it i get this:

You get an empty screen because you add the components to the frame after the frame is visible.

1. As has already been suggested you need to use an appropriate layout manager. FlowLayout is the easiest to start with.
2. invoke `setVisible(true)` AFTER adding the components to the frame.

So the code should be more like:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.add(...);
add(panel);
pack();
setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree to MadProgrammer's suggestions (+1)

Well, lets take a look at your program though

You actually have created a JFrame with components in it. Its working fine as well, but your question of "why are my items not showing up in the JFrame" is not because you did something wrong but because missed out something i.e. revalidate()

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        FirstGUI a = new FirstGUI();
        a.GUI();
        a.revalidate();
    }
```

I'm not saying this will give you perfect UI.. what I'm trying to say is this will help you understand the Swing better. Learn about Swing Layout managers and then work on your UI to have better results

revalidate(): This component and all parents above it are marked as needing to be laid out. This means the Layout Manager will try to realign the components. Often used after removing components. It is possible that some really sharp swing people may miss this. I would think that you will only know this if you are actually using Swing.

Answer (score 1):

The default layout manager for `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`.

This means that your components are essentially all been added ontop of each other.

Try changing the layout manager to something like `FlowLayout` (for example)...

[image]

Take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) for more details.

Also, avoid `setSize` where possible, use [`Window#pack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) instead

**Update**

I'd also like to introduce you to [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) which should be used to launch your UI code...

Answer (score 1):

The only one reason :

```
setVisible(True); method for the frame should be put on the end of the code.
```

if you give this line on the top of the code  that is when you create a frame. This will cause that problem.

Comment: and not calling `revalidate()` after adding components to an already visible frame, also not not being aware of the [Swing's Threading Policy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading)

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the components directly to your frame. Instead add to the *content pane*, which is where a JFrame stores all of the components that it draws. Usually this is a JPanel.

Here is an example:

```
public class GUI
{

    private JPanel content;

    public void GUI
    {
        /*Other code*/

        content = new JPanel();
        add(content); //make content the content pane

        content.add(title);
        content.add(login);
        content.add(pass);
    }
```

If that fails, call `setVisible(true)` and `setEnabled(true)` on all of your components.

On a side note you may want to make your `GUI` function a constructor.

Answer (score -1):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
class Myframec extends JFrame
{

    Myframec()
    {
        Container c = this.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(null);

        this.setBounds(10,10,700,500);
        this.setTitle("Welcome");

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0,0,700,500);
        panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        c.add(panel);
        Font f = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,25);
        Font f1 = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,20);
        JLabel lable = new JLabel();
        lable.setBounds(130,10,400,100);
        lable.setText("Apple Inc. Member Login Port");
        lable.setFont(f);
        panel.add(lable);
        JTextField login = new JTextField("Login",10);
        login.setBounds(120,150,400,30);
        login.setFont(f1);
        panel.add(login);
        JPasswordField pass =new JPasswordField("Password");
        pass.setBounds(120,200,400,30);
        pass.setFont(f1);


        lable.setFont(f);
        panel.add(pass);
        c.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] argm)
    {
        Myframec frame = new Myframec();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of how this code works (by editing the answer).