# Program randomly does not display on startup

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a game in Swing and I'm running into an error where randomly, when opening the program, nothing displays. There's seemingly nothing that triggers it, but I have no idea what could possibly be causing it. And also this is everything in my program that seems to be the problem, Since when i tested the source of the problem, it seems to be that the problem is that it is not rendering anything. My update method is working, but the paint method is not running.

Here is the `gameHandler` class that loads everything and where I believe the problem could be occurring, if this isn't enough to locate the error, please ask me to add whatever it is you would like to see.

```
public class GameHandler 
{

    private GamePanel gp;
    private Player p;
    private StarManager sm;
    private EnemyManager em;
    private UI ui;
    private BulletManager bm;
    private PANEL state;
    private MenuPanel mp;

    public GameHandler(GamePanel gp, Core c)
    {
        this.gp = gp;
        p = new Player(c.getWidth()/2 - 50/2, c.getHeight() - c.getHeight()/4, 25, 50, c);
        sm = new StarManager(50, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), 15);
        em = new EnemyManager(gp, c, p);
        bm = new BulletManager(4, p, em);
        new GameInput(c, p, bm);
        ui = new UI(p);
        mp = new MenuPanel(c);
    }

    public void update()
    {
        state = gp.getState();

        sm.update();
        if(state == PANEL.GAME)
        {
            p.update();
            em.update();
            bm.update();
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        sm.render(g);
        if(state == PANEL.GAME)
        {   
            p.render(g);
            bm.render(g);
            em.render(g);

            ui.render(g);
        }
        else if(state == PANEL.MENU)
        {
            mp.render(g);
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Core extends JComponent implements Runnable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int 
    WIDTH = 800, 
    HEIGHT = 800;

    public boolean running;

    public GamePanel gp;

    public Core()
    {
        new Display(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Geometric Space Invasion", this);
        init();
    }

    public void init()
    {
        gp = new GamePanel(this);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(gp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        running = true;
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Core();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(running)
        {
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(7);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            gp.update();
            gp.repaint();

        }
    }

    public int getWidth()
    { return WIDTH; }

    public int getHeight()
    { return HEIGHT; }

}
```

---

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private GameHandler gh;
    private PANEL state = PANEL.MENU;
    private boolean gameOver;

    public GamePanel(Core c)
    {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        gameOver = false;
        gh = new GameHandler(this, c);
    }

    public void update()
    {
        if(gameOver)
            state = PANEL.MENU;
        gh.update();
    }

    public enum PANEL
    {
        MENU,
        GAME
        /* THIS IS HOW TO CREATE A PANEL VAIRABLE AND CHECK
        private PANEL test = PANEL.MENU;
        if(test == PANEL.MENU)
            //Do whatever.
        */
    }

    public enum DIFFICULTY
    {
        EASY,
        MEDIUM,
        HARD
    }

    public DIFFICULTY diff = DIFFICULTY.MEDIUM; //TODO : REMOVE

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        gh.render(g);
    }

    public DIFFICULTY getDifficulty()
    {
        return diff;
    }

    public PANEL getState()
    {
        return state;
    }

    public void setGameOver(boolean gameOver)
    {
        this.gameOver = gameOver;
    }
}
```

EDIT: FIXED. I fixed it by switching the two lines in the constructor for the Core class.

```
public Core()
{
    new Display(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Geometric Space Invasion", this);
    init();
}
```

became

```
public Core()
{
    init();
    new Display(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Geometric Space Invasion", this);
}
```

Comment: 1) *"if this isn't enough to locate the error, please ask me to add whatever it is you would like to see."* As you seem new to this site, first I'll ask you to go through the [help] and read [ask], it will require you to read how to make a proper [mcve], which isn't your whole code but it isn't code snippets either, not in images or external sites, it should be indented correctly (as I did when I edited your question). 2) For your specific question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409526/why-are-my-items-not-showing-up-in-jframe) in the site...

Comment: ... the solution give might be the same for you (placing `setVisible (true)` on your `JFrame` after adding all your elements to it). Or it could be because of your `render` method breaking the paint chain (depends on how and where it's being called) or your code being multi threaded and one thread depends on the other but starts before the first one has ended (sometimes). Again, having a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/) or MCVE might tell us more (and I'll say it again, it's not your whole code nor code snippets)

Comment: @Frakcool setVisible is called after adding the components. And repaint(); is only called in my game loop, which is visible in the Core class. And also this is everything in my program that seems to be the problem, Since when i tested the source of the problem, it seems to be that the problem is that it is not rendering anything. My update method is working, but the paint method is not running. So the other classes are pretty much irrelevant since I have narrowed it down to these three classes. Should a loading screen fix the problem in order to give it time to load everything?

Comment: I fixed it. added fix into the post.

Comment: @Chrate Please cut&paste it as an answer instead of editing it into the question. Here at SO, question should be question and answers should answer it, even if you answer it yourself.

Comment: Instead of the edit, post an answer with the solution and accept it, so other people knows your question is already solved